# I want to see what is automatically launched at login

Tags: startup, security

I have lent a Mac to a friend.

This friend has access only to a standard account on the Mac.
I trust him, but he is not serious and may download malware accidentally.

I do not want to delete this account because it contains a lot of files/documents.

I just want to get an exhaustive list of all process which are automatically launched when this users log on.

What should I check ? There is no .bashrc for example.

The only thing I can check is "Login Items" in "Users & Groups" Sections (preferences).

But are there config files or other files which allow to start a script or a program when a user logs in?

Comment: There are a lot of places for malware to hide, see https://theevilbit.github.io/beyond/